# Execute Openwrt UCI command through PHP

Tags: php, sh, shell-exec, openwrt

Im developing simple (dead simple) front end for openwrt using PHP. To do this I need to call many openwrt UCI (Unified conf. interface) commands through PHP shell_exec() or system() functions. All the UCI commands that I tried in terminal are working perfectly fine. But as soon as I run them through above functions they are simply not working.

As an example I run following two commands which worked well in terminal

```
uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].ssid=test
uci commit
```

But as soon as I run them through PHP nothing happens. They are simply not working. The I make .sh file and save above two lines and run that files using PHP but again!! results are the same. But when I execute .sh file through terminal it works!!

For testing I set the both file permission to 777. but that doesn't helps. Is there are any additional requirements to run shell commands through PHP like root access to the PHP or Apache ? I'm new to this and I would thankful if someone can help

my apache error_log

```
[Wed Aug 19 08:26:53 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.117] uci
[Wed Aug 19 08:26:53 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.117] : 
[Wed Aug 19 08:26:53 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.117] I/O error
[Wed Aug 19 08:26:53 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.117]
```

Im using apache as a web server and openwrt Chaos Calmer 15.05-rc3 as my base firmware on top of Raspberry pi 2

Comment: I am trying to do same thing from Node server any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using uhttpd web server instead of Apache. Apache somehow doesn't have enough privileges to execute UCI commands directly. uhttpd the default web server in openwrt can execute this commands directly

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure out the same problem and my conclusion so far is run php with root permissions. I know this is not secure, but at least it works. Here is **one line** from `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` to run php-fpm with root privileges:

`service_start $PROG -R -y $CONFIG -g $SERVICE_PID_FILE`

---

The key flag here:
-R, --allow-to-run-as-root
 Allow pool to run as root (disabled by default)

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are right. What [sameera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767359/sameera) mentions was the fact that **uhttpd** has special rights running on LEDE or OPENWRT (as default), but what [Anton Glukhov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285202/anton-glukhov) wrote is also correct, it allowed me to run as root but limited to avoid errors. I was not able to run my scripts (.sh) as with **uhttpd**, but php runs ok and does not have any bugs while running as root. I guess its a file permissions issue by default on Nginx with Openwrt. My solution was leave uhttpd running on a different port and run my program with all the rights and permissions while running everything else as non root in Nginx. Security is no issue in my case, its offline server.

```
service_start $PROG -R -y $CONFIG -g $SERVICE_PID_FILE
```

Works, in my case editing adding the `-R` flag in `/etc/init.d/php7-fpm`