# execute shell commands in OpenWrt with Node.js (+ express) server

Tags: node.js, express, openwrt

I have a networking scenario as shown in here
[image]

When ever someone is connected to router, server **/GET** should check client's ( connected device's) information from OpenWrt router to do so, internet says executing shell command on OpenWrt  UCI (Unified conf. interface) will works.[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044209/execute-openwrt-uci-command-through-php/57068972#57068972)  post says it worked with **php**  `shell_exec()` or `system()` functions, so I used `child_process` on node server and did following

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  exec("[my shell commands]", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
   console.log(error || stdout || stderr);
 });
});
```

but this is run on my server, I'm looking for help to run this commands on Openwrt router,
Thank you

Comment: Try running this in LXC on the router.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. could you please tell me how this can solve my problem,

Comment: Last sentence in your question says you're looking to run this on the router. I'm saying run this in LXC.